# memory debugger for c++

Tags: c++

one of the most part in programming is debug problem and increase performance ( i think! ), and I never did serious debug because I just write small programs.

but this time i write a program that little big, and i doubt there is some problems in memory.

so I want a debugger that do the following:

- support c++ .
- check if there is leak memory .
- calculate the size of memory that my application allocate .
- check every function or object separately .
- using GUI ( graphical user interface  )  .

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux try using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It does everything you specified.

Comment: +1. valgrind also works in macosx

Answer (score 1):

Check out [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).  With those two tools you should be able to do what you want.  Having said that they're not GUI's, but that's not a downside.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's run time libraries [have lots of useful functions to track memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx). Only works on Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you should check out [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg).